# android - can not setvisiblity view.invisible for view with default view.gone

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I have a view with view.gone as default. When running app, I use setvisiblity view.visibile to bring it back but nothing happens.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/pnl_actions">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="48dip"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            android:id="@+id/btn_quick_reply"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/edit_quick_reply_blue"
            android:background="#eee"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_edit"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="48dip"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            android:id="@+id/btn_edit"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/edit_blue"
            android:background="#eee"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because in your parent `layout` you have

```
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

either change this to

```
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

or a fixed `width`, which I don't recommend. Or change the `visibility` of the `View` to `invisible` instead of `gone` in your xml.

When the `layout` is first drawn, that space isn't available with the properties you have set. With my recommendations, the space will still be there to be used by another `View`. You could also change the `width` of the parent `layout` programmatically when you want to change the `visibility` of your `ImageView` but that would be more work and probably unnecessary in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/pnl_actions">
```

Add orientation and make sure that there is enough space for the item to appear, it should look like this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/pnl_actions">
```

Comment: `LinearLayout` has a horizontal `orienation` by default so this will have no affect. Meaning, if you leave out the `orientation` property then the `layout` will be `horizontal`.